# Data backup from wordpress subdomain sites

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Is there any method or way to take backup of all my mysql data from my wordpress site/blog made on wordpress.com as its subdomain site

i means
my site is suppose abc.wordpress.com

then how can i be able to take data backups from my wp admin panel ( or by other ways )

Answer (score 0):

if you take a look at wp codex [proposed solutions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Backing_Up_Your_Database) for backing up your wp database - with a clean wp installation, you can't do it from your dashboard.

but, you can backup your wp database with [WP-DBManager](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-dbmanager/) plugin if that is a good enough solution for you.